# excel error 424 object required when calling sub

Tags: excel, vba

I spent hours looking into my code but I can't figure out what is wrong.

I keep getting this 424 error, for no obvious reason to me. here is my piece of code.

I just want to give row as a parameter to mySub to process it.

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub mySub(row As Range)
    Debug.Print ("mySub") ' not printed
    Dim line As Collection

    Set line = New Collection
End Sub

Private Sub CalcClients()
    Dim data_sheet As Worksheet
    Dim last_row As Long
    Dim last_col As String
    Dim line As Long
    Dim cols As Range
    Dim row As Range

    Set data_sheet = Worksheets("DATA")
    Let last_row = data_sheet.Range("A1").End(xlDown).row
    Let last_col = Col_Letter(data_sheet.Range("A1").End(xlToRight).column)
    Set cols = data_sheet.Range("A2:" & last_col & last_row)

    For Each row In cols.Rows
        ' type_name(row) => "Range"
        Debug.Print (row.Cells(1, 1).Value) '=> THEEXPECTEDVALUE
        mySub (row) ' Error 424, object required
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Add a `call` before it.

Comment: Where is the error occurring?

Comment: @BruceWayne `mySub (row) ' Error 424, object required`

Comment: @findwindow, that worked ! what magic is that ?

Comment: Ancient Tibetan magic =P Just syntax. You could also remove the `()` and it should work too ^_^ Edit: if you remove `()`, also remove the `call`.

Comment: indeed! This is srsly wtf to me!

Comment: lol yea I hate when code dies due to syntax. Just something you know or you don't XD

Comment: @Micka Please remove the question if you have solved it yourself

Comment: @findwindow, post your answer so I can accept it.

Comment: @CrakC - replacing `Next` with `Next row` would never make a difference. VBA always knows which loop it is in. So that additional word is not necessary and, some say, might even slow down performance.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here is the reason for the observed behavior.

Your subroutine, `mySub()` takes one parameter as a range type.

This means you must pass it a range.

In your code you set an object variable `row` to a series of ranges, one at a time.

To use that range variable `row` as a parameter for `mySub` the syntax should be like this:

```
mySub row
```

Or...

```
Call mySub(row)
```

...but instead you are doing this:

```
mySub (row)
```

So, what's the difference? When you place parentheses around any variable that is standing alone (as in the above), that variable gets evaluated immediately and prior to whatever you plan to do with it.

The parentheses are a common way to override a procedure's ByRef argument and instead force a one-time ByVal parameter pass. This is because the parentheses force an evaluation of the variable and the resultant VALUE is passed instead of a reference to the variable.

In your case, you do not want to do this (in fact, in most cases you do not want to do this). **When you sandwich `row` with parentheses, the range object is no longer passed to the routine**. Instead it is evaluated and its values are passed as a Variant Array.

And since the `mySub` definition calls for a range object parameter, you get error 424. `mySub` is complaining, "Hey, this is not a range object and a range object is required!"

Comment: @findwindow Hmm. I see you are serious. That's sad. I thought you were jesting. Sorry, I don't agree with your sentiment. You only told how to avoid the error. I fully explained why it happens.

Comment: I was jesting but didn't think you were.

Comment: This VBA stuff is maddening.

Answer (score 5):

Add a `call` before it. You could also remove the `()` and it should work too ^_^ If you remove `()`, also remove the `call`.