# Calling methods of a user-defined class without keyword "call"

Tags: excel, vba

In the following code, tests 1,2 and 3 compile, but test 3 fails at run-time with "object doesn't support this property or method": ( why?)

```
Sub testdrive()

    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim val As Single
    Dim myfoo As New CFoo

    ' test 1
    val = 4
    myfoo.sub1 (val)

    ' test 2
    Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
    Call myfoo.sub2(sh)

    ' test 3
    myfoo.sub2 (sh)

End Sub
```

The class module contains only the following:

```
Public f As Single

Public Sub sub2(sh As Worksheet)

End Sub

Public Sub sub1(s As Single)

End Sub
```

I cannot find a definitive statement of when I am obliged to use the "call" keyword.

Can anybody enlighten me?

Comment: Where is it failing?  What line?

Comment: What is the error message about call?

Comment: Have you tried removing the `()`?

Comment: You never have to use Call... but if you do, you must surround the full list of parameters with one set (total) of parentheses. If you are NOT using Call then you should not use parentheses around any parameters, unless you intend for that parameter to be evaluated prior to the call and hence passes as a ByVal copy.

Comment: fails on the line      myfoo.sub2 (sh)

Comment: Removing the brackets () around the sh argument solved it! Thank you very much to all of you speedy responders.  However, I am bemused about the rule at work here, and wonder it there is a way that I can continue to use bracket notation, or know how to anticipate when it will not work. Thx!!

Comment: It's pretty simple. Don't use parentheses around the parameter list when providing parameters to a Sub... unless you use the Call keyword.

Comment: Thx Excel Hero I just noticed your reply regarding the rules for call and parentheses. Very helpful, I will put it to the test.

Comment: @foobar you can upvote the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33356019/excel-error-424-object-required-when-calling-sub/33356299#33356299)

Answer (score 1):

When you parenthesize a parameter without using the keyword `Call`, in VBA syntax, this means that you want to force evaluating it then passing *its Value*. For VBA, the only way to achieve this is to *evaluate the parameter then pass its value to the subroutine*.

This works well if the parameter is a simple type, such as `Single`, so it works for `Public Sub sub1(s As Single)` then `sub1(something)` works fine.

BUT when the parameter is a worksheet, such as in `Public Sub sub2(sh As Worksheet)`, when calling `sub2(sh)` with parenthesis, you are asking VBA to *evaluate* the worksheet, which it does not know how to achieve. Basically, `Worksheet` is not an object that VBA can *evaluate*. Therefore, it says

> *this object does not have this property or method*

It means: the class `Worksheet` does not have a *default property* such as `.Value`, which on the other hand exists for a `Range` object, for example.

You cannot parenthesize the worksheet argument, unless you use the keyword `Call`, which prevents its prior evaluation.

```
Call myfoo.sub2(sh) '<~~ works fine
myfoo.sub2 sh '<~~ works fine
myfoo.sub2(sh) '<~~ problem, you are asking VBA to evaluate sh and pass its value
```

Finally, note that this has nothing to do with the fact that your Subs are class methods. It would have been the same if they were normal subroutines, placed in a normal code module.

Comment: Thx ASH appreciate the elaboration. Now crystal clear!