# Error when calling sub Run-Time Error '424': Object Required

Tags: excel, vba

## BIG PICTURE

1. Go through a list and create a tab for each item in the list (Working)
2. Create a hyperlink in the list that links to the associated worksheet (Working)
3. Create basic header information on each worksheet and hyperlink back to index sheet (Working)
4. Insert a button for each reference listed in a corresponding cell in the index sheet and hyperlink to that pdf, doc, or docx file (Not working, work in progress)

## CURRENT PROBLEM

When calling the sub that will insert buttons I am getting an Object Required error (see image at end).

The main part of the code is as follows:

```
Sub CreateTabs()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim NameArray As Variant
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim x As Long
Dim y As Long
Dim z As Long
Dim ReferenceCount As Long
Dim RefSplit() As Variant

    LastRow = FindLastRow
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
    NameArray = ws.Range(ws.Cells(2, 1), ws.Cells(LastRow, 1)).Value
    For x = LBound(NameArray) To UBound(NameArray)
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add(after:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count)).Name = NameArray(x, 1)
        'ws.Hyperlinks.Add ws.Cells(x + 1, 1), "", ThisWorkbook.Sheets(NameArray(x, 1)).Cells(1, 1).Address(External:=True), NameArray(x, 1), NameArray(x, 1)
        With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(NameArray(x, 1))
            ws.Hyperlinks.Add ws.Cells(x + 1, 1), "", .Cells(1, 1).Address(External:=True), .Name, .Name
            .Hyperlinks.Add .Cells(1, 1), "", ws.Cells(1, 1).Address(External:=True), "Item List", "ITEM LIST"
            .Cells(2, 1) = "Item"
            .Cells(3, 1) = "Description"
            .Cells(4, 1) = "U.O.M."
            .Cells(6, 1) = "Specifications"
            .Cells(2, 2).Formula = "=RIGHT(CELL(""filename"",$B$2),LEN(CELL(""filename"",$B$2))-FIND(""]"",CELL(""filename"",$B$2)))"
            .Cells(3, 2).Formula = "=VLOOKUP($B$2,Sheet1!$A$2:$D$" & LastRow & ",2,0)"
            .Cells(4, 2).Formula = "=VLOOKUP($B$2,Sheet1!$A$2:$D$" & LastRow & ",4,0)"
            
            ReferenceCount = Num_Characters_In_String(ws.Cells(x + 1, 3).Value, ", ") + 1
            ReDim RefSplit(1 To ReferenceCount,1)
            If ReferenceCount > 1 Then
                RefSplit = ReferenceSplit(ws.Cells(x + 1, 3).Value)
            Else
                RefSplit(1,1) = ws.Cells(x + 1, 3).Value
            End If
            
            z = 1
            
            For y = 1 To ReferenceCount
                If y > z * 5 Then z = z + 1
'*************************************************************
                Call Insertbutton(z, y - (z - 1) * 5, RefSplit(y, 1).Value, ThisWorkbook.Sheets(NameArray(x, 1)))
'*************************************************************
            Next y
                
        End With
    Next x
End Sub
```

And the sub that is being called looks as follows for now:

```
Sub Insertbutton(btnrow As Long, btncol As Long, btnName As String, ws As Worksheet)

Dim btn As Button
Dim rng As Range

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    ws.Buttons.Delete 'probably do not need as it is fresh sheet

    Set rng = ws.Cells(btnrow + 6, btncol + 1)
    Set btn = ws.Buttons.Add(rng.Left, rng.Top, rng.Width, rng.Height)
    
    With btn
        If Left(btnName, 1) = "F" Then
            If Num_Characters_In_String(btnName, "-") = 2 Then
                .OnAction = "P:\2019\1234-name space\08. Working\Specifications\Section F" & btnName & "*.doc*"
            Else
                .OnAction = "P:\2019\1234-name space\10. Construction\01. Tender\F\" & btnName & ".pdf"
            End If
        Else
            .OnAction = "P:\2019\1234-name space\10. Construction\01. Tender\OPSS\OPSS*" & btnName & "*.pdf"
        End If
        .Caption = btnName
        .Name = btnName
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

[image: Error Pic]

## QUESTION

**What is the missing object?  What am I doing wrong with the call?**

(I foresee some issues with linking to the files but I have not got to that point in my debugging yet, and that will be a different question.  Trying not to muddy the waters so to speak)

I did read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33356019/excel-error-424-object-required-when-calling-sub) so I believe the format of the call ( ) is correct, but I could be wrong

Comment: If the crash occurs on the procedure call the culprit should be `ThisWorkbook.Sheets(NameArray(x, 1))`. Assign this to a variable just before the call and see whether the worksheet actually exists. The other 3 arguments shouldn't be capable of causing the error you have but I would pass them ByVal rather than ByRef (the default, since you mention nothing).

Comment: If the crash comes after the call, look at  `ws.Buttons.Delete`. This would definitely cause the error you have if the buttons you delete don't exist. Sandwich the command between `On Error Resume Next` and `On Error GoTo 0`.

Comment: I would ask what line of the code is causing the error? Is it at the header of the function `Insertbutton` or within?

Comment: Just something to consider if you don't actually like using buttons on worksheets (I don't) - you could add hyperlinks instead of buttons? You're using a button as a link anyway so why not just stick with hyperlinks? If you need code to execute then use the worksheet_followhyperlink event.

Comment: @variatus, The error is being called at the call.  I placed a break in the first line of the called sub and the error came up before I ever reached it.  I changed the sub to by val for first three and by ref for last one. The sheet exists as it is placing the button is all part of the sheet set up and I can see the new sheet created and named along with basic info before error crashes things.

Comment: @Dean it would be a combination of the sub header and call.  I could not even get to the first line of the sub where I had placed a break.  I removed the .value as suggested in the answer below, AND changed passing variables using byVal as suggested and I seem to be moving forward.

Comment: @jamheadart, I originaly was trying to keep all the reference numbers in one cell separated by line feed and then was going to try to line up a shape beside each one with a hyperlink assigned to it.  That started to look complex and I did not have an exact path to the file I want opened.  With wild cards in the path I can narrow it down to a unique entry, but that is the part I still have not fully worked through. and will probably be a separate question.

Comment: Ah I see, that makes a lot of sense. You could always use a generic hyperlink to act as a button and then use the `followHyperlink` event to do the code that points to the right links etc. It's effectively a button, I just hate using actual command buttons, and particularly creating them dynamically, on a worksheet - they're so prone to resize issues etc.

Comment: Yes. I also think many CommandButtons are apain in the neck. But to solve your call problem you must create the Ws object before you use it as an argument. And if it turns out that it isn't the Ws then do the same for each of the argument. By doing so you force the error to occur before the call instead of in the call. That was you can deal with it. I'm afraid that's the only way. I see you already found an answer. By the method I describe you would have found it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

**RefSplit(y, 1).Value** causes an error. **RefSplit(y, 1)** is correct.

Do not use .value for arrays. Because it is used for range objects, an object error occurs.

```
Call Insertbutton(z, y - (z - 1) * 5, RefSplit(y, 1).Value, ThisWorkbook.Sheets(NameArray(x, 1)))
```

However, there is another error, and the type of the argument cannot be matched. String variables should be used.

```
Dim myString As String
myString = RefSplit(y, 1)
Call Insertbutton(Z, y - (Z - 1) * 5, myString, ThisWorkbook.Sheets(NameArray(x, 1)))
```

Comment: so how does one convert an array entry holding a string to a string?

Comment: I removed the .value, and changed the sub header to byval and it now seems to work

Comment: @ForwardEd you can use `CStr(myArray(y,x))` to convert an array value to a string